# C# FileWatcher File not free after reading

Tags: c#, file-io

I just started with C#, and i tried to create create a FileWatcher, which should print the content of a File, if it is changed:

```
{
    public static void watch()
    {
      FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
      watcher.Path = "Path";
      watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
      watcher.Filter = "Filter";
      watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
      watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (TextReader r = File.OpenText("Path")) {
         while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null) {
              Console.WriteLine(s);
         }
         r.Close();
      }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        watch();
    }
}
```

So far the FileWatcher is working fine, but if I try to print the content it works once and no matter how long I wait the programm will stop working on the second change.
As far as I understood the "using" statement should free the file. The close command does not change anything at all.

The file is a very small text file and should not be a problem.

Is there anyway to force the program to free the File?

Comment: Perhaps your `watcher` object is being collected. Try promoting it to a field.

Comment: Would you tell us the exception that your program throws?

Comment: Not an answer (the problem lies elsewhere) but a suggestion: Change your `OnChanged()` to `Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("Path"));`

Comment: sasha_gud Answer is working perfectly, Problem was TextReader. Solving with StreamReader is working. Thank you all for your Suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileReadTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static FileSystemWatcher watch()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = "d:\\";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "test.txt";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            return watcher;

        }
        public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string s;

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(File.Open("d:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
            {
                while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var watcher = watch();
            Console.ReadKey();
            watcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've changed file reading routine to avoid some reading problems when a file is opened by an other program. `FileSystemWatcher` will also not get out of scope and will not be disposed accidentally.

Comment: Looks very good, i was looking for this. I will try tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true`, in your case want to use `watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All)`, to make your program wait for changes indefinitely.

BTW, the statement `r.Close()` is redundant because you are already implicitly call `Dispose()` via `using`, which in turn calls `Close()`.

EDIT: To be more specific: `WaitForChanged` of course just waits for one change and then returns, so if you want to wait for more changes, you can use a loop. Note that no event handler is needed if you use it this way.

```
while(true)
{
    watcher.WaitForChanged(WaitForChanged.All);
    // Do stuff with the changed file here, no event handler needed
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (in my now working Code) and for the `r.Close` your obvious right. But i tried changing the Watcher, as you suggested but it just prints the first change. So maybe `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true)` works better in my case.

Comment: Yes, well, that's what the method `WaitForChanged` does - it waits for one change and then returns. To continue waiting for the next change, you have to do a loop. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing to do is debug and verify if your method `OnChanged` gets called only once or also at the following edits of the monitored file, then you already know if the issue is with the lifetime / scope of the watcher or somewhere else.

Is this a console application? does it close or stays open after you call the watch method in the main?

Comment: I will try, but as i already wrote, without the Textreader everything works fine, so i guess its the Reader which doesnt free the resource correctly.  The Programm is a console application, which monitores a file all the time and i try to read it after every change.

Answer (score -4):

You need to dispose the FileSystemWatcher.

```
public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (TextReader r = File.OpenText("Path")) {
         while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null) {
              Console.WriteLine(s);
         }
         r.Close();
      }
      File((FileSystemWatcher)sender).Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Er... uh... `File((FileSystemWatcher)sender).Dispose();`... What?